# Train simple models on android without server

Tags: android, machine-learning

I'm new to machine learning and I was wondering if it is possible to train models on smartphone. I know recognising objects in images  needs huge models and is expensive and it is advised to train model on computer. But machine learning isn't all about recognizing images or voices.

Let's say I want to predict (that is just an example) when employees will drink coffee based on the day of week and hour (all data is stored on smartphone)

Where do I start? What libraries should I use? I don't want any data to be sent to or from. server

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with [Google ML-Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/).

If you are familiar with [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) (Google's machine learning framework), **[Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/)** the official solution for running machine learning models on mobile, should let you build, train, test & run your ML model easily offline (on your smartphone).